# Do Maple questions belong to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, migration

I just found a [Maple question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47929085/maple-dont-evaluate) and was wondering where they belong. They seem more Math.SE oriented, but I don't have experience in Maple in order to tell. We also have a [Maple tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maple), which, by glancing at the scores of the questions, don't seem to be well received. The questions over at [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maple), however, are better received. We need to make a decision so the questions aren't split up, causing duplicates.

Comment: I used Maple a bit, and I would definitely classify it as a programming software. So, if the question concerns the *programming, scripting* part, I think it should be on-topic. However, the question you linked looks awfully off-topic here. No programming/code question, only math stuff or simple usage of the GUI, *apparently*  (the question is pretty unclear IMHO)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maple is a computer algebra system, primarily used for solving mathematical problems symbolically. This is very much programming. The same goes for questions about programming with Mathematica or doing symbolic computations in python using the sympy module (just to take examples from my personal experience). I agree with [the comment by Pac0](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360983/do-maple-questions-belong-to-stack-overflow?cb=1#comment541908_360983) that the specific question wasn't a good fit for Stack Overflow, but not because it's about maple.

The fact that the maple tag has very low traffic only suggests that one might have more luck with asking on math.SE; there's probably a higher ratio of mathematicians than developers who use maple. This doesn't change the fact that these questions are also on topic here. Stack Exchange sites can easily overlap in scope. Until there is a dedicated sister site (akin to [Mathematica.SE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)) for them, I believe maple questions are certainly on topic here.

Answer (score 1):

As it happens, pretty much the same question was [asked a few weeks ago on meta.math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27515/how-to-properly-handle-maple-related-questions).

The general consensus seems to be that computer algebra systems like Maple, Maxima, Magma, Gap, Sage, etc. are essentially *programmable tools* for solving mathematical problems, and so questions about them are on-topic at both SO and math.SE.  However, you will likely get very different answers on the two sites.

Basically, if you'd like to ask a question about *programming* in Maple, SO is a good choice, whereas if you'd like to ask about *solving a mathematical problem* using Maple, you may find math.SE a better choice.

Unfortunately, it's also possible that you may not get a good answer on either site.  CASes like Maple are fairly specialized tools, with not a lot of experts on them in the first place, and Maple isn't even the most popular tool within that specialized niche.  And both SO and math.SE are fairly busy sites where it's easy for questions on less popular topics to go unnoticed.  While one *can* ask Maple questions on the SE network, and might even get answers for them, I kind of suspect that asking on Maple-specific site like [MaplePrimes](https://www.mapleprimes.com/) may be more effective on average.

<sup>(Disclaimer: While I've used Maple a bit and know a thing or two about it, I'm hardly an expert on it myself.  And I've never really used the MaplePrimes site that I just linked to.)</sup>